# Simple SQL query but huge table - how to optimize?

Tags: mysql

I've got this very simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT target FROM table WHERE goal_id=1 AND year>=2015 AND year<=2020
```

The table has about 5 millions rows, though. And as a result, it's very slow (about 10 seconds).

What could I do to improve things? Would an index help, and if so on which column?

Comment: Show the create table to see the indexes already have and then also a EXPLAIN of your query.  But simply said a combined INDEX on goal_id and year shoild move things along.

Comment: ...depending on how many distinct `goal_id` values there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal index for *that* query is

```
INDEX(goal_id, year, target)
```

*in that order*.  And regardless of the cardinality of any of the columns.

1. Start with the `=` test(s)
2. Add on at most one range (the two `year` tests are effectively one "range")
3. Add on all the other columns found anywhere in the query; this makes the index "covering" for another boost.  Now the entire query is performed in the index's BTree, without also having to bounce over to the data's BTree.

(That is a simplification.  For more details and varied cases: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql )

But...  That query looks like it might return lots and lots of rows.  If so, you may be network-bound.  If so, then think about whether you can do more processing in SQL without shoveling a million rows to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following and it seems to work well so far. Thanks for all the tips!

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX index_name (year, goal_id)
```

Comment: Try to swap fields in the index expression - especially if `goal_id` have more than 7 distinct values.